# Coding error on Trading View pine script "Error at 13:0 Mismatched input 'sma' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'."

Tags: tradingview-api

Coding error on Trading View pine script "Error at 13:0 Mismatched input 'sma' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'." 13 is the one that says "sma = 0.0" below.

```
//@version=4
study("CLARITY ALGO FREE", overlay=true)
slow = input(21, title="Slow EMA")
//ema definitions
emaSlow = ema(close, slow)
sma(src, length) =>
sma = 0.0
sma := na(sma[1]) ? sum(src, length)/length : (sma[1]*(length-1)+src)/length
sma
smaFast = sma(close, 9)
//Color definition for Moving Averages
col = close > emaSlow ? color.lime : close < emaSlow ? color.red : color.yellow
//Moving Average Plots and Fill
p1 = plot(emaSlow, title="Slow MA", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=4, color=col)
p2 = plot(smaFast, title="Fast MA", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=col)
fill(p1, p2, color=col, transp=70)
plotshape(crossover(smaFast, emaSlow), style=shape.triangleup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, text="Buy", title="Buy", location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(crossover(emaSlow, smaFast), style=shape.triangledown, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, text="Sell", title="Sell")
alertcondition(crossover(emaSlow, smaFast), title="Sell", message="Sell")
alertcondition(crossover(smaFast, emaSlow), title="Buy", message="Buy")
```

I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Are you using chatGPT? Due to such poor accuracy Stackoverflow has [banned ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). TradingView has also decided [not to provide support](http://tradingview.com/chart/TRAIA/XwwZ70ar-Our-take-on-AI-generated-Pine-Script/) for ChatGPT.

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation error :
after the line declaring the function
sma(src, length) =>
you should have a tab before each of the three lines in this function :

```
sma(src, length) =>
    sma = 0.0
    sma := na(sma[1]) ? sum(src, length)/length : (sma[1]*(length-1)+src)/length
    sma
```